# Ubuntu 18.10 GRUB2 wont recognize APFS filesystem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, filesystem

Is there any way for GRUB2 to recognize the APFS filesystem for booting? If not is there a menu entry configuration that would allow manual loading of macOS?

Im suprised not to find anyone else having this issue. I guess everyone is using rEFInd? I'd prefer not to use rEFInd as GRUB was taking over half the time anyway which was probably due to the `fallback.efi` (which I don't want to bother with)

Ubuntu 18.10 is currently installed on a 256 Gb SD card and GRUB was installed to the unpartitioned primary macOS drive /dev/sda

Answer (score 0):

APFS file system is currently not supported on Linux at all, there is only an experimental FUSE (not kernel) driver to mount it in read-only - https://github.com/sgan81/apfs-fuse an commercial driver by Paragon

So, there is obviously no support for APFS in GRUB2 too.

Comment: So GRUB and Linux kernel are separate, correct? That is, even with Paragon’s driver, GRUB would still not recognize the APFS, right?

Comment: Yes, of course. Thing is that Grub uses Linux kernel code (partially) to make its use of various filesystems, but since there is no kernel support for APFS then GRUB dev have nothing to work with.
Commercial drive will grant you only ability to mount APFS partition for read\write.

Comment: Darn, is support for APFS something foreseeable? Or will devs just stick with the support for HFS for good?

Comment: I dont see even mention of APFS in GRUB2 mailing list and given that its quite fresh FS and Apple didnt posted (yet) any documents about its structure its very hard to predict anything.

Comment: Ahh I see, well thank you for all your insight - hope Apple will post soon

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share with you all that I had both high sierra and Linux Mint on my old 2012 iMac and out of nothing I can't make use of the "alt/option" key command to choose High sierra (on that grey window at startup that is gone)
Now I can only use Mint. Grub never worked and couple weeks ago I understood why none of my moves worked.
Later on (like you all), I realized that (grub) UBuntu/Mint does not recognize APFS file system. And for some reason that screen is gone and no keyboard shortcut allows me to access the recovery mode to reinstall High Sierra...
What I am going to do is, take my ssd out take to someone whith HSierra installed back important recordings I have made that day and format the drive and install a HPSF+ File system so I can access files and make grub work.
Just use Mac OS for some few audio applications (professionally)

I don't believe that APFS file system will get supported that soon...